# Flutter / Dart - Limit a generic to a class that implements X or Y interface and ... use the methods inherited from the abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, inheritance

I understand that the generic can be limited to inherit, extend, implement X or Y class, whether abstract or not.

```
Future<void> getInfo<T extends BaseModel>({required String extraUri})
```

But how can I use the methods that that interface gives to its children?
Something like:

```
T.inheritMethodCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass object to this function and call method:

```
  Future<void> getInfo<T extends BaseModel>(T t, {required String extraUri}) {
    t.inheritMethodCall();
  }
```